# Dart List consisting of Lists (i.e. 2d array) weirdly linked

Tags: arrays, list, dart, multidimensional-array

I was just trying to create a 2D array in Dart as follows:

```
List<List<int>> data = List.filled(7, List.filled(15, 0));
  
data[1][0] = 5;
  
for (int i = 0; i< 7; i++) {
  print('Index $i: ${data[i]}');
}
```

Expected result would be:

```
Index 0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 1: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 3: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 4: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 6: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Actual result is:

```
Index 0: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 1: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 2: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 3: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 4: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 5: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 6: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

It seems that the lists are somehow linked. Why is that and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This is explained by the [`List.filled` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.filled.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using [`List.filled`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.6/dart-core/List/List.filled.html), which creates a list where all elements will point to the object you provide as the second argument.

Since your second element is a `List` object, then your first will now have 15 references that point to that single `List` instance. This is why it seems like you have changed all sublists when doing a change to one of them.

What you instead want to do is create a new sublist for each position in your first `List`. To do this, you can use [`List.generate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.6/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) like showed in this example:

```dart
void main() {
  List<List<int>> data = List.generate(7, (_) => List.filled(15, 0));

  data[1][0] = 5;

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    print('Index $i: ${data[i]}');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Index 0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 1: [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 3: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 4: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Index 6: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here we now call `List.filled` for each sublist we want in our first `List`, which means we now end up with individual `List` objects so any change to one of them will not seem to happen in the other ones.